# JavaScript Node.JS - ${variable} no works

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, get

i started lerning Node.JS few days ago and i found little bit problem my JavaScript syntax no works at all in Node.JS i hope someone can tell me why, here are Code Examples,

Working Code :

```
const request = https.get("api.api/zip=94040&apiid=randomkey125dessd", () => { ... })
```

Doesnt Work (error 404), zip is constant and api is JSON with property key:

```
const request = https.get("api.api/zip=${zip}&apiid=${api.key}", () => { ... })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [Template litterals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) wrong.

---

This is

```
https.get(`api.api/zip=${zip}&apiid=${api.key}`,
```

and not

```
https.get("api.api/zip=${zip}&apiid=${api.key}",
```

Comment: no work 

when i type API in varriable it telling me wrong apikey or wrong zip and both are in "var zip = 94040";

Comment: I don't get your problem

Comment: simple when i call get() method with api=4dsadsa6d... it works but when i use ${api.key} it no works tryed your "" and ' ' but nothing helps 

https://teamtreehouse.com/community/nodejs-api-and-city-code-is-wrong-and-api-key-is-wrong